# Link works although page was moved to another location

Tags: permalinks

I am a new to WordPress. Please help me with the following issue.

I created page A and set Parent to X, hence its permalink was displayed as "http://websitename/index.php/X/A/".

In page B, I reference to page A by the attaching the link "http://websitename/index.php/X/A/" there

I then changed Parent of page A from X to Y. The permalink of A thus was updated as: "http://websitename/index.php/Y/A/"

I visit page B again and click on link "http://websitename/index.php/X/A/", it still works and brings me to link "http://websitename/index.php/Y/A/"

I wonder how it could happen? I was expecting to see Page Not Found or something like that as link "http://websitename/index.php/X/A/" is no longer available.

There probably is something I don't know about how the link in WordPress works.
Can somebody please help explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### That is called *canonical redirect*.

And it's done through [`redirect_canonical()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/) which basically

> Redirects incoming links to the *proper URL* based on the site url.

and

> Will also *attempt to find the correct link* when a user enters a URL
>   that does not exist based on *exact* WordPress query.

(Those excerpts were both taken from the function's [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/).)

So in your case, although the post parent of `A` has changed from `X` to `Y`, the post `A` (or a post with that slug) still exists, and therefore, when you visit the old URL:

```
http://websitename/index.php/X/A/ (old URL - post parent is X)
```

with canonical redirect, you'd be redirected to the correct URL:

```
http://websitename/index.php/Y/A/ (new URL - post parent is Y)
```

and not being presented with a `404` (page not found) error page.

Try visiting `http://websitename/index.php/A/` and you'd see the canonical redirect being applied.

And if you visit `http://websitename/index.php/A123z/`, assuming there are no post with `A123z` as the slug, then you'd see the 404 error page.

Comment: Thanks for your information, Sally!

Does that mean I just can leave it the way it is and the moved pages will be automatically found without having to direct them to the new URLs? As I was worry that the pages just accidentally show because of caching.

Comment: Yes, you can leave that behavior, which is default in WordPress. It's unlikely caching issue, but you can disable all plugins to confirm that. [This post](https://www.dev4press.com/blog/wordpress/2015/canonical-redirect-problem-and-solutions/) has a more in-depth explanation regarding canonical redirects in WordPress - the info are mostly still valid despite the post date. Alternatively, just Google for "canonical redirect wordpress" without the quotes.. :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help you. =)